# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) ? wordpress install

Tags: wordpress, xampp, localhost

I installed [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/fr/index.html) and runing Apache and Mysql then download wordpress put the folder in XAMPP and edit *config-wp-sample.php* to *config-wp.php* and edit database name and password.
After that when i write in browser https//localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php 
I got the blank page then i set 'WP_DEBUG' to true in config-wp.php

I got these message

```
 Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1531
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It usually happens when you enter the wrong mysql username or password. For XAMPP the default username is 'root' and default password is None (empty).

From your error

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I assume you used some password with the username root. Try again without password or [create a new user account](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2242/how-to-create-separate-users-in-phpmyadmin-each-one-cant-see-others-databases) from phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

This error message usually appears when the MYSQL credentials are not right.

Please check the **username** or the **password** and be sure they are correct.